# Getting "InvalidArgumentError" in TensorFlow when working on MNIST data

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm following a Udemy course and a beginner with CNN with TensorFlow. When I'm running a session I'm getting `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10]` error.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for step in range(1000):

        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

        sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})

    # Evaluate the model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))

    # Output will be like [True, False, True.....] --> Cast to [1.0, 0.0, 1.0.....]
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))

    print(sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_true:mnist.test.labels}))
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1326     try:
-> 1327       return fn(*args)
   1328     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1305                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1306                                    status, run_metadata)
   1307 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-1df33799cd1a> in <module>()
      7         batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
      8 
----> 9         sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
     10 
     11     # Evaluate the model

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1122     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1123       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1124                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1125     else:
   1126       results = []

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1319     if handle is None:
   1320       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1321                            options, run_metadata)
   1322     else:
   1323       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1338         except KeyError:
   1339           pass
-> 1340       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1341 
   1342   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder_1', defined at:
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2802, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-23-12e74ec33d57>", line 2, in <module>
    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1548, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2094, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/majain/anaconda3/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
`
```

Answer (score 0):

**The dimensions of y_true and mnist.test.labels should be consistent.Hope can help you.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you haven't initialized the placeholder variables. 
Tensorflow constructs a computation graph by using statements that you have written.
So when you write:
sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_true:mnist.test.labels})
TensorFlow searches what all things it requires to calculate acc and recursively it looks for other variables.

The error tells that one of the placeholder variable isn't initialized or initialized in a wrong way.

You are feeding wrong variable names in feed_dict. Tensorflow is looking for y_true for computing cross_entropy step but you are feeding it "y". Make following change Computation graph sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y_true:batch_y})

Comment: please find the gist here https://gist.github.com/yum-dev/7fce82eb7e5e058f1965b4daf55bc536

Comment: You are feeding wrong variable names in feed_dict. Tensorflow is looking for y_true for computing cross_entropy step but you are feeding it "y".
Make following change
Computation graph sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y_true:batch_y})